# Turkish Doctor death report for Neil MacNeill Campbell died 1895, Hasskeni, Turkiye

Tags: 19th-century, death-records, turkey

How would I obtain access to the death record of Neil MacNeil Campbell died 25 October 1895, physician presiding Dr. Kanas.  Turkish law usually required parents name on doctor’s report.  I have the British Consulate - FA 005207, dated 26 October 1895.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I think the current name for Hasskeni is Hasköy, a neighborhood on the Golden Horn opposite Balat, a neighborhood of Istanbul. Based on https://books.google.com/books?id=6QAB37-gZ5UC&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=hasskeni&source=bl&ots=4pG5pb8tum&sig=ACfU3U0KL_Dxf97adY0ICss0CuvU-HTAiw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjon9nfwaP5AhWqlmoFHdT_CmkQ6AF6BAgkEAM#v=onepage&q=hasskeni&f=false  . The only references I can find to Hasskeni are from the mid-late 1800s.

Comment: Also https://books.google.com/books?id=lhcPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=hasskeni&source=bl&ots=bjo4-0WVHz&sig=ACfU3U0g25tW8LEWsNg7Hdvv3qSsrYUfmA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUpZqIxKP5AhWGkGoFHfo7B7oQ6AF6BAgjEAM#v=onepage&q=hasskeni&f=false , where Cassim Pacha is Kasımpaşa